# Chart.js: stack the bars to the left

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need to stack the bars in the bar chart to the left as per the image attached
[image: Bar chart]

is there a way to do that in chart.js?

EDIT:

Just to clarify what I am looking for.
The number of the bars in my chart is dynamic, if there are 10 of them then chart looks fine but if there are only 2 they each take 50% of the width of the chart (see picture #2)

[image: picture #2]

I want both of those bars to be exactly the same width as if there were 10 of them and be stacked to the left.

One option that I'm currently considering is just to add (10 - no of bars) bars with 0 value so that they won't be visible. But I'm hoping that there is a better solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart ?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a graph with  10 empty bar charts, then populate it with your values, I think it would be better to add empty values to reach the number of 10 (*same idea though*).

If you take a look in the Chart.js documentation, you can see that [you can create plugins](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins) for your charts and graphs. Plugins are extremely useful when editing your chart (*instead of just hardcoding what you want*) since they allow you to handle what is happening while creating your charts.
For instance : `beforeUpdate`, `afterDraw` are some of the events you can handle with plugins.

---

Now, you must know that the chart object contains a lot of information :

- If you want to edit a global option, you'd check `chart.config.options`
- If you want to edit a specific chart, you'd check `chart.config.data`

In our case, we'd need the `data` attribute.
If you take a deep look in it, you'd see that the number of values come from the lengh of both `data.labels` and `data.datasets[`**`n`**`].data` (***n*** being the **n**th dataset).

---

Now that you know *what* to do, and *how* to do it, you can do it.

I still made a quick example of what you are looking for :

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

// stores the number of bars you have at the beginning.
var length = -1;

// creates a new plugin
Chart.pluginService.register({

  // before the update ..
  beforeUpdate: function(chart) {
    var data = chart.config.data;
    for (var i = data.labels.length; i < data.maxBarNumber; i++) {
      length = (length == -1) ? i : length;
      // populates both arrays with default values, you can put anything though
      data.labels[i] = i;
      data.datasets[0].data[i] = 0;
    }
  },

  // after the update ..
  afterUpdate: function(chart) {
    console.log(chart);
    var data = chart.config.data;
    if (length == -1) return;

    // prevents new charts to be drawn
    for (var i = length; i < data.maxBarNumber; i++) {
      data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[i].draw = function() {
        return
      };
    }
  }
});

var data = {

  // change here depending on how many bar charts you can have
  maxBarNumber: 10,
  labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  datasets: [{
    label: "dataset",
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  }]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: false
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's what I meant by adding (10 - no of bars) of empty values. This reads 10 minus number of bars. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. 

This is the best answer so far so I'll mark it as the solution. 

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reverse()` to reverse the data if it is currently stacked to the right. Otherwise you will need to use some type of sorting to go from largest data to smallest data.